# Which hashing algorithm is suited for image local descriptors?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, hash, knn

I run a sliding-window (akin to a convolution kernel) on an image and extract the means/color histograms for each window. However since the data is very high dimensional I wish to hash it as a signature, so I can perform approximate Nearest neighbor image searching by aggregating the windows.

```
>>> means = cv2.mean(roi) #roi = window
>>> means
(181.12238527002307, 199.18315040165433, 206.514296508391, 0.0)..... => **some numeric hash**
```

Which hashing algorithm is appropriate for this situation? I have tried Md5 and SHA-1, but those are cryptographic and probably unsuited for k-NN.

I have read about MinHash and SimHash, but unsure if they are suited for my usecase. Any suggestions?

[sliding window image example](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/sliding_window_example.gif)

Comment: **None of the popular ones (by design the opposite of what you want)!** You want some perceptive-hashing or Locality-preserving-hashing. But most of these used for images will start with an untouched image (meaning: what you are doing as first steps is not part of their design). Another remark (from a non-expert): that sliding-window looks way to huge (will not be able to grasp edges which are arguably the most important concept) to do anything good in your case.

Comment: which ones are you referring to? is it possible to adapt the perceptual hash or locality hash to generate "local" descriptors?

Comment: No. They are typically used as an hash for a complete image. Hash(a), Hash(b) -> hashes follow some metric (e.g. in euclidean-space) behaviour  so that clustering-based approaches can work with these.

Comment: Can you not store your hashes into a 2-dim array based on the x/y position in the image?  Or skip the hash completely and just store the info?  I guess I am missing part of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I was trying to employ some dimensionality reduction, since each window has 3 channels, storing them in 2d array can get very intensive. And also necessitates performing pair-wise comparison, for each channel, across each window, for every image which is astronomically complex.

Comment: @greybeard: the data consists of feature vectors. If you are familiar with opencv, these are like `SURF`, `SIFT` etc. I have a custom feature vector because of the unique nature of our imagery, but they are essentially descriptors of color/shape/texture etc.

Comment: @greybeard: _"hash values are great at excluding things as not possibly equal, but generally no good in gauging similarity or even equivalence"_ is incorrect. There is a class of hashing algorithms known as Locality sensitive Hashing (LSH) - MinHash is a simple popular one - which hash similar vectors to the same bucket with high probability.

Comment: Check the [OpenCV FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html) that contains a collection of algorithms that's ideal for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Locality Sensitive Hashing (LSH) is a good candidate for your purpose. According to *["Near-Optimal Hashing Algorithms for Approximate Nearest Neighbor in High Dimensions" (by Alexandr Andoni and Piotr Indyk)"](https://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/p117-andoni.pdf)*, it is suitable for performing approximate search in high dimensional spaces.

The characteristic of the hash functions employed in LSH is that their **probability of collision is higher for feature vectors that are close to each other than for those that are far apart**. Cryptographic hash functions don't have this property. With a crypto-hash, even a very small change in your feature vector will produce an extensive change in the hash value.

[OpenCV FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html) has an implementation of LSH. Also the authors of the above paper provide an implementation [here](http://web.mit.edu/andoni/www/LSH/).

Having said that, I suggest you evaluate other algorithms in OpenCV FLANN on your dataset, so you can select the best one.

Regarding the features, you are basically using color information that are very sensitive to illumination. May be illumination is irrelevant in your case. Better if you can try other feature descriptors (SIFT/SURF, ORB, BRIEF and many more) and evaluate their performance with different algorithms.